# Scaling an Azure Mobile Service in a SaaS Solution

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services, saas

I am working on hosting a SaaS solution on Azure that is using elastic sql auzre for multi-tenant scenario. The client will communicate with the back-end via Azure Mobile Services. Mobile services provides auto scale capabilities on standard tier. My question is that will this auto-scale be sufficient for a product app with thousands of API calls? or should I consider some other setup such as multiple mobile services in different locations? CDN's etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely.  Azure App Service Mobile Apps can scale up to 10,000 API requests per second.  Beyond that, you need to think more closely about architecture, which is a bigger question.

Comment: thats my question exactly! how to do load balancing/failover with Azure Mobile Services